# Cobol DB2 SQL query - NOT IN parameter

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

Is it possible to have something like this :

```
MOVE "'xx','yy','mm''" TO WS-TYPE-PARAM;
```

Then in SQL Query :

```
SELECT bar
  FROM tblfoo
 WHERE bar_type NOT IN (:WS-TYPE-PARAM)
```

I tried but unsucess. Maybe there's an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99% Sure the answer is no.  (With RPG that would be 100%)

You have to pass in a variable for each value

```
SELECT bar FROM tblfoo WHERE bar_type NOT IN (:WS-TYPE-PARAM1 : WS-TYPE-PARAM2 : WS-TYPE-PARAM3)
```

You could do it with dynamic SQL  (sorry it's RPG)

```
wSqlStmt = 'SELECT bar FROM tblfoo WHERE bar_type NOT IN (' + WS-TYPE-PARM + ')';
```

Normally however, such dynamic SQL is a bad idea.  For both performance and security reasons; 
The above dynamic code is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.  But as long as the values in WS-TYPE-PARM are not coming from a user it's safe.

The last option would be to insert the values into a temporary table, then just

```
SELECT bar FROM tblfoo WHERE bar_type NOT IN (SELECT type_parm FROM tmptable)
```

Comment: I see. .thanks man. Your answer totally removed my confusion. :)